# Creating persistent ADODB connection on workbook/worksheet opening

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

Right now I have an Excel worksheet full of hundreds (if not thousands) of functions, each one individually opening an ADODB connection to my SQL Server, executing a command, then closing the connection - this has led to some lengthy waiting periods while refreshing data.

```
Public Function Alere(StoredProcedure As String, paramItem As Range)
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
connString = [connection string]
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("[query]")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Alere = rs(0)
Else
    Alere = "-"
End If
End Function
```

Would it be possible to open my connection on worksheet_activate(), and have it persist so that I can just reference it at any point? I have attempted putting the following at the top of the module:

```
Public conn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open ("DSN=" & Worksheets("Variables").[H2] & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=" & Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & ";DATABASE=" & 
Worksheets("Variables").[H3])
```

...but I get issues regarding "Set" not being allowed outside of a function/sub.
So is there any way to have the connection persist and I simply continue to execute commands through it?

Comment: put the public declarations in a module (name it globals if you want) then put your Sets and open code into the Workbook.Open event, when do you want the connection to open when you are on the sheet or when you open the workbook?  When would you like to close the connection? You could make 3 buttons - make connection, refresh your formulas, and close connection instead . . . .

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I've placed the public declarations in my module, and the sets in a Workbook.Open event in ThisWorkbook. However, the function now returns a #VALUE! error...

Comment: what line throws the error?

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code never mind, changing the module seems to terminate the connection for whatever reason... your solution worked, thank you! if you submit it as an answer I will gladly accept it

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to close the connection in the workbook beforeclose event or something manual like a button.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code what happens if connections are not closed?

Comment: Could use a lot of memory on your computer, there are discussions about setting objects to nothing and closing connections, it could hinder either your CPU or Memory, also if a pipe is already open and you try and re-open it (server log on) some of those fail, as some servers do not allow a user to log on multiple times simultaneously.  Maybe nothing bad happens, it is accepted code practice to clean up after yourself just to be sure, I am pretty sure your open pipe would close when the workbook closes (VBA has Garbage Collection and scope definition).  Perhaps M. Guidon or Vitaya will know.